# How to properly test the method returning Task object in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, javafx, junit

I am facing problem testing method that returns Task object of `javafx.concurrent.Task` package. When I run the test, the program aborts and it fails to create new `BasicDataSource` object and doesn't even throw any exceptions and the test passes too. So it is difficult to trace the exact problem. Imo, it is probably related to threading but not exactly sure.

Connection Pool code snippet (Problem originates here):

```
public synchronized static DataSource getDataSource() {

        try {

            Properties property = new Properties();
            URL url = SessionManager.class.getResource("/properties/database.properties");
            property.load(new FileInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(url).getFile()));
            if (dataSource == null) {
                synchronized (ConnectionPool.class) {

                    if (dataSource == null)
                        dataSource = new BasicDataSource(); //Program aborts here
                }
            }
            
            dataSource.setUrl(property.getProperty("DB_URL"));
            dataSource.setUsername(property.getProperty("DB_USERNAME"));
            dataSource.setPassword(property.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD"));
            dataSource.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(property.getProperty("DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS")));
            dataSource.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(Integer.parseInt(property.getProperty("DB_MAX_PREPARED_STATEMENTS")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Junit 5 Test Snippet:

```
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void initJavaFxToolkit() {

        // Initialize the JavaFX toolkit
        Platform.startup(() -> {
        });
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() {

        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test if user credentials pass on correct credentials")
    void testIfUserCredentialsPassOnCorrectCredentials() {

        LoginCredentials loginCredentials = new LoginCredentials("organization", "Hello123#", true);
        Validator login = new Login(loginCredentials);

        Task<AuthenticationStatus> task = login.getUserValidationStatus();
        Platform.runLater(() -> task.setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> assertEquals(AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS, task.getValue())));
    }
```

Method where first time `getDataSource()` is called

```
    @Override
    public Optional<Long> retrieveUserId(String username) throws SQLException {

        String sql = "SELECT user_id FROM personal_details WHERE username = ?";

        //problem occurs down here
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionPool.getDataSource().getConnection()) {

            //rest of code
    }
```

Task returning method:

```
    @Override
    public synchronized Task<AuthenticationStatus> getUserValidationStatus() {

        Task<AuthenticationStatus> loginTask = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected AuthenticationStatus call() {

                //rest of code

                Optional<Long> optionalUserID = retrieveUserId(username); //problem
                userID = optionalUserID.orElse(0L);

                //rest of code
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(loginTask);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
        return loginTask;
    }
```

As you can see in Test snippet, I tried to initialize JavaFX toolkit so that FXApplicationThread is created but that didn't help.

Note: The application runs fine when executing the non-test/source code.

Comment: can you explain how you want to provide a database connection within your Test? Do you want to use an Test-Database (may an in-memory DB like H2DB)  or do you want to mock your Database using a mocking Framework like Mokito or use an DB-Simulator? Do you try to use your develop-DB in Tests?
It is important to know since otherwise we cannot give an answer

Comment: @MartinFrank Hello. No I am not using anything you mentioned. Infact this is my first time using Junit required for college project. As for database connection, I am just calling method (Test code snippet) getUserValidationStatus which in turns call retrieveUserId method which contains code to get connection from connection pool.

Comment: usually the test run during build - on a machine that has no access to a database connection. When this happens your code will not work - you already found out, where it will not work (`Connection connection = ConnectionPool.getDataSource().getConnection()`)

Comment: so  - you have to prove a TEST-DATABASE in a way, any way you want - but if you DO NOT your specific Test wont work.
If all of that is no option for you have a look at the **DIP - Dependency Inversion Principle** - your professor will love you for this ^^ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Comment: One problem is that you have the assertion code inside a callback that is itself added inside a `Platform.runLater` call. That means the test will return, and thus succeed, likely before the assertions are even executed. Given you don't care about blocking the thread during this unit test, see if doing something like `assertEquals(SUCCESS, task.get())` works for you. That `get()` method comes from the `Future` interface. It also throws checked exceptions, so you have to handle them in the test (I would just declare a `throws` clause, as propagating an exception will fail the test).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for help. But it still doesn't throw exception. The problem of program aborting remains when creating new DataSource object.

Comment: @MartinFrank How to prove it? Is there any guide that can help with my problem which doesn't use Spring or JPA or anything advanced that I am not using? All guides are based on them.

Comment: Another problem you have is you catch all exceptions in `getDataSource()`. That method can't handle an exception meaningfully; it should let the exception propagate, possibly by rethrowing it wrapped in an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

### Dependency inversion principle

it says that high level classes should not be dependent of low level classes

**bad example:**
[image]

your `OnlineShop` is strongly dependent on your `CatalogDatabase`. this is evil, since you cannot test your Shop without having a database prepared.

**good example:**
[image]

your Onlineshop only know that there is an **interface** of a Catalog - you can now **replace** the database-catalog with a test-catalog. There is even a constructor that tells you which database you choose.

**...then what?**
when you have implemented DIP you will be able to replace your connection with a test-connection. you can provide a test-connecxtion, that does the stuff you want it to do. It can even go further, you could test bad cases as well - and your tests will be independent where they run. on a build-server, on your local machine, on ...where ever you want....

### summary

i do not know where and how you create instances of `ConnectionPool`, `DataSource` and `Connection` - but you must make them replaceable! (your code does not provide where it happens).

As a friendly note: **DO NOT USE STATIC METHODS** - they will always make it harder for you (even if it makes everything easier in the beginning)